# JDA Discord Bot with Lavaplayer not working properly on Raspberry Pi 3B+ (Raspbian)

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, discord, raspbian, lavaplayer

I have recently written a **Discord Bot** in **JDA**. Because its a bot I´m only using on my Servers, **I don´t need an dedicated Server for this**, a Raspberry Pi is enough (yes I am aware of the low specs but they are enough for me). 
So what I did then was **installing Java on the Pi** (I used Version 11 cause its the most recent one), **copied my Botfiles to my Pi** and started them by navigating into the folder I put them in and executing `java -jar lxxrxtzBot.jar`. **The Bot started up fine** and I was able to use the commands - however **not the MusicBot Commands**. In the Bot I am using the **Lavaplayer** but if I start using my Play-Command the **Bot either connects to my channel and plays nothing** or **connects and disconnects** again after around 2 seconds.

However if I run the Bot **on my Windows Computer everything works fine** (I am executing this in cmd with `java -jar lxxrxtzBot.jar`). If I use Musicbot-Commands while Bot hosted on my Windows PC the Bot doesnt disconnect - **it simply plays the Music**.

I am really wondering why that isn´t the case on my **Pi 3B+ with Raspbian** and I hope somebody can come up with a solution to my Problem.

Thanks for reading this, have a nice day ^^

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Your first question looks like a nice one, however we would need more details to help you out. What is your code? What do you use? What exactly is your error?

Comment: I think all of your questions are answerded in that Text, dont they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah nvm everyone,

**I've fixed it:**

I've **downloaded this [libconnector.so file](https://github.com/zekroTJA/DiscordBot/blob/master/out/artifacts/DiscordBot_jar/libconnector.so?raw=true)** here. Then I went to my **Bot-JAR File, right-clicked it and opened it with WinRAR**. I **opened the natives/linux-arm/ folder and pasted the libconnector.so file there**.
Then I **copied the modified .jar-File to my Pi** 3B+ with Raspbian and **executed it in the Terminal with `java -jar lxxrxtzBot.jar`**(Replace `lxxrxtzBot` with your .jar-File Name)

**Now everything works perfectly!**

If you see this Thread cause you have the same problem, use this method ^^

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

LavaPlayer doesn't support ARM. There is an open [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/sedmelluq/lavaplayer/issues/16).

Comment: Ok, is there a workaround for that in Order to get it working? Cause I´ve seen that [someone](https://github.com/sedmelluq/lavaplayer/issues/16#issuecomment-375907453) there said that he copied a libconnect.so file to another location which let him use it? what is that file and where do i get that from? do you get how hes doing that?